# Rate of Return / Standard Deviation / Correlation Coefficient - Mathematical Finance

Tags: statistics, finance, economics

Consider these two stocks: AT&T Inc. (T) and Verizon Communications Inc. (VZ). Use the daily adjusted closing prices from March 1, 2015 to August 12, 2015 as historical data.

1. Estimate the mean rate of return and the standard deviation of each of these assets. Moreover estimate their correlation coefficient ρ, and their covariance.
2. Using their correlation coefficient ρ, find the weight of each of these assets that will give an efficient portfolio with minimum variance. Deduce the return of that portfolio.

Comment: Do you have any data about the daily adjusted closing prices from March 1, 2015 to August 12, 2015 ?

Comment: The AT&T Inc. (T) closing prices can be found here: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=T&a=02&b=1&c=2015&d=07&e=12&f=2015&g=d And the Verizon Communications Inc. (VZ) closing prices can be found here: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=VZ&a=02&b=1&c=2015&d=07&e=12&f=2015&g=d

Comment: You have to be a little bit more specific about your problems. Do you have problems to evaluate the rate of return of the assets or the standard deviation of the assets ? I cannot answer the whole two parts of the exercise at once.

Comment: I m having more difficulty evaluating the rate of return of the assets

Answer (score 1):

The rate of return  of stock $AT \& T$ is

$$ r_t^T=\frac{PCA_t^T-PCA_{t-1}^T}{PCA_{t-1}^T} $$

T is the index name of $AT \& T$. t is the index for the $t^{th}$ day.

PCA is the close price adjusted for dividends and splits.

The standard deviation of the rate of return of  $AT \& T$ is

$$\sigma^T =\sqrt{\frac1n \times \sum_{t=1}^n \left( r_t^T-\mu^T \right) ^2 }$$

with $\mu^T= \frac1n\sum_{t=1}^n r_t^T$